# Randomly thrown NullReferenceException in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I'm trying to authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth. Unfortunatelly, I get a NullReferenceException when calling FindFolders() (code below). But, what is interensting - not always, just sametimes. Is anyone facing this issue too and can help me with this?

This is code you should be interested in:

```
var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("hidden")
                .WithClientSecret("hidden")
                .WithTenantId("hidden")
                .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
                .Build();

            var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

            try
            {
                var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token

                var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
                ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
                
                ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId =
                            new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "mail");

                //Include x-anchormailbox header
                ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "mail");

                // Make an EWS call
                var folders = ewsClient.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new FolderView(15));

                foreach (var folder in folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(folder.DisplayName);
                }
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}");
            }
```

What I've already tried is cloning this repository https://github.com/pawelFelcyn/ews-managed-api instead of installing nuget package. And it helped, as I could find where the exception is being thrown. It's in ServiceRequestBase.WrapStream(), becuase contentEncoding is null (you can see this on github - the file is in folder Core/Requests). I've just added a simple nullcheck like this:

```
 if (contentEncoding is null)
 {
    return responseStream;
 }
```

But this brings some other problems. As I understood, version of this library on github does not support somethig connected with Xml, what I need. Can anyone help me, please?